Using Azure Devops API (Python) to write comments on PR
Haven't been able to find a direct method for this anywhere. How can I add comments to a pull request via Azure Devops API in Python?

We have the sample API to create a new thread with a comment for a pull request.
We can also call another API in this sample to add a new comment in an existing thread of a pull request.
Here is my python script for your reference.
import base64
import json
import requests

# Define your Azure DevOps organization, project, repo, pull request id and personal access token
organization = "YourADOOrgName"
project = "TheProjectName"
repository_name = "RepoName"
pull_request_id = 108
personal_access_token = 'xxxxxx'

# Encode the personal access token in base64
base64_pat = base64.b64encode(f':{personal_access_token}'.encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Basic {base64_pat}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Define the URL for a new thread of the PR
thread_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_name}/pullRequests/{pull_request_id}/threads?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

thread_body = {
    "comments": [
        {
            "parentCommentId": 0,
            "content": "Test comment 1 by Python in another thread",
            "commentType": 1
        }
    ],
    "status": "active"
}

# Make the API request to create a thread with comment
thread_response = requests.post(thread_url, headers=headers, json=thread_body).json()

# Print the response of the new thread and the id
print(json.dumps(thread_response, indent=4))

thread_id = thread_response.get('id')
print(f"The new thread id is {thread_id}")

# Define the URL for a comment in an exsiting thread
thread_comment_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_name}/pullRequests/{pull_request_id}/threads/{thread_id}/comments?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

thread_comment_body = {
  "content": "Test comment 2 by Python in another thread",
  "parentCommentId": 1,
  "commentType": 1
}

# Make the API request to create a comment in the exsiting thread
thread_comment_response = requests.post(thread_comment_url, headers=headers, json=thread_comment_body).json()

# Print the response of the new comment
print(json.dumps(thread_comment_response, indent=4))


Per the follow-up query to set the thread status, we can call this API to update the status value as one of those in the CommentThreadsStatus.
# Generate URL to update thread status
update_thread_url = f"https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repository_name}/pullRequests/{pull_request_id}/threads/{thread_id}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

update_thread_body = {
  "status": "fixed"
}

# Make the API request to update thread status
update_thread_response = requests.patch(update_thread_url, headers=headers, json=update_thread_body).json()

# Print the response of the updated thread
print(json.dumps(update_thread_response, indent=4))



Appreciate this! I wanted to know how we can set the status of a comment though - I was reading the code in the ADO python repo but could not determine what status should look like in Comment class.

Hi @probonocoda, I have updated the answer as per your follow-up query to set the comment status. Hope it can resolve your questions in this post. Thx for your time and efforts. Good luck with your works to go and have a productive week ahead.
